# ldap filter in CAS configuration

Tags: search, filter, ldap, cas

I need to run a CAS server (v3.5.2) connected with an Openldap directory.

The problem is that i need to filter every search on 2 fields:

- uid=%u (the classical search)
- accountEnabled=TRUE (a filter to see if the account is able to login to the CAS server)

According to that, i specified the following configuration in the **deployerConfigContext.xml**

```xml
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler" >
  <property name="filter" value="(&(uid=%u,ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=org)(accountEnabled=TRUE))" />
  <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource" />
</bean>
```

Using that configuration cause the failure of starting CAS server and i can see that error in the tomcat logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 132 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 132; columnNumber: 39; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

Do you know any way to make this configuration working?
Thanks by advance for any answer.

---

After modifying the conf following the xml syntax, i'm getting the following java error when i'm trying to log in on the CAS server:

```
2014-01-06 11:27:07,640 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler threw error authenticating [username: myuser]>

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLScheme(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:337)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getURLOrDefaultInitDirCtx(InitialDirContext.java:106)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267)
    at org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler$1.executeSearch(BindLdapAuthenticationHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:292)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:360)
    at org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler.authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal(BindLdapAuthenticationHandler.java:90)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler.doAuthentication(AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler.java:71)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate_aroundBody2(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:85)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate_aroundBody3$advice(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:57)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:1)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl.authenticateAndObtainPrincipal(AuthenticationManagerImpl.java:93)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody0(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:57)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody1$advice(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:57)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect$1.proceed(AbstractTimingAspect.java:47)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AgnosticTimingAspect.runProfiledMethod(AgnosticTimingAspect.java:53)
at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect.doPerfLogging(AbstractTimingAspect.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.createTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody10(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:477)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.createTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody11$advice(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.createTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect$1.proceed(AbstractTimingAspect.java:47)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AgnosticTimingAspect.runProfiledMethod(AgnosticTimingAspect.java:53)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect.doPerfLogging(AbstractTimingAspect.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.createTicketGrantingTicket(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction.submit_aroundBody2(AuthenticationViaFormAction.java:109)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction.submit_aroundBody3$advice(AuthenticationViaFormAction.java:57)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction.submit(AuthenticationViaFormAction.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:851)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1253)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1329)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.ognl.OgnlExpression.getValue(OgnlExpression.java:85)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody2(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:128)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody3$advice(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:57)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:1)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I tested my ldap filter with a ldap_search command, it's working.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `&` with `&amp;`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML.

Comment: Thanks, you're right i added it and the cas server is starting. Anyway when i try to login on the auth page, cas is displaying a nullpointer exception :/